# How can I make windows always show full folder path

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, shortcuts, path

Whenever I Click on "Desktop" in windows explorer, I end up with a "hidden" path, such as this:

[image: http://content.screencast.com/users/slapshot136/folders/Jing/media/1c25a6f2-845d-4bbe-98a4-6cf873784ce3/2015-04-05_1304.png]

which makes navigating to the "one up" folder hard (I can enter a folder within desktop, then navigate "two up")

Is there any way I can get it to display like this instead:

[image: http://content.screencast.com/users/slapshot136/folders/Jing/media/7de2c035-26ea-40c5-82f8-d2c1547142af/2015-04-05_1305.png]

(result achieved by navigation from the C drive)

I am not looking for a "manual shortcut", as the built-in "Desktop" shortcut appears in a lot of places and I would much rather have that one function properly instead

Comment: If you click on the arrow to the right of the word "Desktop", you will get a dropdown. The parent of Desktop is your user folder, usually the one with your name,

Comment: @JulianKnight - well, that helps a lot, thanks! (still going to leave this open just in case there is a way to get the path there though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Desktop is a top-level folder which is why you can't go higher.

But you can navigate to it by typing %USERPROFILE%\Desktop to get the full path. You will not see all files, because `Desktop` combines both `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` and `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop`.

This is the same as Libraries. They're not actual folders, but are collections of different folders and thus you cannot navigate to a higher folder.

Creating or modifying a shortcut to these locations won't work, as Windows automatically turns it into the `Desktop` collection. A shortcut to is the best you can do. Question becomes, to where, your desktop, or the public (all users) desktop?

Comment: Well if I had a choice id choose "my" desktop (I just picked one of the users for a sample..)

Comment: Adding on to the OP's question if I may. What if the folder I am in is myFolder, located in D:\XYZ\myFolder. Can the address bar be customized to show full address? Right now, it shows "Computer" > "NewVolume(D:)" >"XYZ" > "myFolder"

Comment: @George yes that is possible (at least showing it in the title bar all the time (setting), or on command in that location (by clicking next to it)), but given that its solution is different from what I've written here, can you please search SuperUser? I think it already was posted once. If you can't find it, feel free to post a question on your own and you'll get your answer there.